# How to assign a modified object's values back to the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to modify one object that has a part of a value that I want in this case the letter after the dash, and I want to assign only the latter back to the target object, any ideal how to do this I want to be able to push the returned array back in to itemsObject or in to a new object ?
so in final the items object should have a : 'A' , b : 'B'.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // context.items = {a: '1-A', b :'2-B'}
    let modify = Object.values(context.items).map((value) => {
      return value.split('-');
    });
   // itemsObject = {a : '', b : ''}
    SetLink(Object.assign(itemsObject, context.items /*or new obj that will have the new values*/));
  }, []);
  
  
  // End Result 
  
  // itemsObject = {a : 'A', b : 'B'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) from your original `itemsObject` and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each key to an array of the form `[key, value]`, where the value is the value after the dash `-` from your `context.items` object at the particular `key` you're mapping. You can then wrap the mapped array of keys in a call to [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) which will build your new object for you:

```js
const items = {a: '1-A', b :'2-B'}; // context.items
const itemsObject = {a: '', b: ''};

const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(itemsObject).map(key => [
  key,
  items[key].split("-").pop()
]));
console.log(res); // setLink(res);
```

Comment: The code will work fine, just one little optimisation, If we are sure that the value in the object will always be of the format `{x}-{y}` and both `x` and `y` are of length 1, then the return value of map can be **[key, items[key][2]**.

Comment: @ManishKumar yep, you're right, that would work also  I suppose OP can find the best method for them to extract the letter from the string as I'm not too sure what the exact format will be like either.

Comment: @NickParsons thanks nick, works like charm, any idea how , to split without losing the first part in case you want to implement that part in to something else ? I mean the -

Comment: @Richardson do you mean to keep both the number and the dash? If so you can change `items[key].split("-").pop()` to be just `items[key]`

Comment: @NickParsons no i meant I want 1- the first part of the string without losing the -

Comment: @Richardson You could replace everything after the dash with an empty string, so you could use `items[key].replace(/(?<=-).*/g, '')`, otherwise you could use something like this `items[key].split("-").shift() + "-"` or `items[key].split("-")[0] + "-"`